# Date formatting in pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, merge, type-conversion

I have 2 two data frames.

```
Date       thing
201712.0    1
201801.0    2
```

The Date column is float64 type and I am trying to convert it to date of 12/1/2017 and 1/1/2018 respectively.

```
Date        thing2
12/16/2017    2
1/16/2018     3
```

The Date column here is object type and I hope to convert to 12/1/2017 and 1/1/2018 as well. The idea here is to do a pd.merge after.

Comment: Is the date column on 1st dataframe `float` type or `str` type?

Comment: the first data frame Date column is float64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [pandas.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) to convert the `'Date'` columns of your original dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[201712.0, 1], [201801.0, 2]], columns=["Date", "thing"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([["12/16/2017", 2], ["1/16/2018", 3]], columns=["Date", "thing2"])

df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'].astype(str), format='%Y%m.0')
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date']).apply(lambda x : x.replace(day=1))
```

In the first dataframe, `'Date'` column is converted to string type (the `.astype(str)`) stuff) in order to use a format string.
In the second dataframe, `apply` function is used to reset the day of the month to the first from whatever it was in the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

You need:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y%m') + pd.Timedelta(days=16)
```

Output:

```
        Date    thing
0   2017-12-16  1
1   2018-01-16  2
```